# convert normal data set to market basket analysis process-able format

Tags: r, arules

I had created one data set as shown below for applying market basket analysis(apriori())

```
id  name
1   mango
1   apple
1   grapes
2   apple
2   carrot
3   mango
3   apple
4   apple
4   carrot
4   grapes
5   strawberry
6   guava
6   strawberry
6   bananas
7   bananas
8   guava
8   strawberry
8   pineapple
9   mango
9   apple
9   blueberries
10  black grapes
11  pomogranate
12  black grapes
12  pomogranate
12  carrot
12  custard apple
```

I applied some logic to convert it into  market basket analysis process-able data.

```
library(arules)
fact <- data.frame(lapply(frt,as.factor))
trans <- as(fact, 'transactions')
```

and I tried this one also and got an error.

```
trans1 = read.transactions(file = frt, format = "single", sep = ",",cols=c("id","name"))

Error in scan(file = file, what = "", sep = sep, quiet = TRUE, nlines = 1) : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection
```

the output that I got is not as expected.
output I got.

```
items                transactionID
1   {name=mango}                   1  
2   {name=apple}                   2  
3   {name=grapes}                  3  
4   {name=apple}                   4  
5   {name=carrot}                  5  
6   {name=mango}                   6  
7   {name=apple}                   7  
8   {name=apple}                   8  
9   {name=carrot}                  9  
10  {name=grapes}                  10 
11  {name=strawberry}              11 
12  {name=guava}                   12 
13  {name=strawberry}              13 
14  {name=bananas}                 14
```

my expected output is

```
id  item
1  {mango,apple,grapes)
2  {apple,carrot}
3  {mango,apple}
```

and so on like this

so can any one please help a way to get my expected output(if it's possible)

> so that it helps me to apply apriori() algorithm.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: is this an `arules` question?  And what is `frt`?

Comment: would it help to gather the fruits in base R like `with(frt, aggregate(name ~ id, frt, toString))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing market basket analysis in `arules`, you need to construct a `transactions`. You can do this from your text file like:

```
write.csv(frt,file="temp.csv", row.names=FALSE) # say "temp.csv" is your text file
tranx <- read.transactions(file="temp.csv",format="single", sep=",", cols=c("id","name"))
inspect(tranx)
#     items           transactionID
# 1  {apple,                      
#     grapes,                     
#     mango}                    1 
# 2  {black-grapes}             10
# 3  {pomogranate}              11
# 4  {black-grapes,               
#     carrot,                     
#     custard-apple,              
#     pomogranate}              12
```

...**or**, if you have already read your text file into a `data.frame`, you can coerce it into a `transactions` through a list object like:

```
tranx2 <- list()
for(i in unique(frt$id)){
  tranx2[[i]] <- unlist(frt$name[frt$id==i])
}

inspect(as(tranx2,'transactions'))

#   items          
# 1  {apple,        
#   grapes,       
#   mango}        
# 2  {apple,        
#   carrot}       
# 3  {apple,        
#   mango}        
# 4  {apple,        
#   carrot,       
#   grapes}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your guidance it helped me a very lot. But one thing I can't get is what's  the need of the second part of your code(program) can you please say it.

Comment: @Dinesh you should do the first part if you are starting from a text file.  You should do the second part if you are starting from a data.frame called `frt`.  Your question was not clear, so I gave you the option.  You do not need to do both.